# ThreeJS not animating glb file. stuck on first frame

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality

Trying to animate glb file within 8th wall using ThreeJS for an Augmented Reality experience.

```
    // Load 3D model
    loader.load(
      // resource URL
      modelFile,
      // loaded handler
      (gltf) => {
        model = gltf.scene
        scene.add(model)
        // Hide 3D model until image target is detected.
        model.visible = false
        
      }
    )


  // Places content over image target
  const showTarget = ({detail}) => {
    // When the image target named 'model-target' is detected, show 3D model.
    // This string must match the name of the image target uploaded to 8th Wall.
    if (detail.name === 'model-target') {
      model.position.copy(detail.position)
      model.quaternion.copy(detail.rotation)
      model.scale.set(detail.scale, detail.scale, detail.scale)
      model.visible = true
      model.play = true
    }
```

Thanks for your help.